# Failed to deploy: Automatic rollback disabled for this deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, aws-lambda, aws-code-deploy, cloud9

I am trying to run [Deploy multiple machine learning models for inference on AWS Lambda and Amazon EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/deploy-multiple-machine-learning-models-for-inference-on-aws-lambda-and-amazon-efs/), I have done all the steps correctly, however, when I use the `sam build --use-container` command, I was falling into memory error.

In order to solve this problem I resizing EBS volume manually to 30 Gib and I used the `sam build --debug --use-container` command because I realized that *cloud9* and my *runtime* had different versions of python.

After much research and trying I was able to build it successfully. But, when I went to deploy, using the command `sam deploy --guided`, I got the following:

```
CREATE_FAILED                         AWS::Lambda::Function                 MLModelUploadFunction                 Resource handler returned message:  
                                                                                                                  "'MemorySize' value failed to       
                                                                                                                  satisfy constraint: Member must     
                                                                                                                  have value less than or equal to    
                                                                                                                  3008 (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 
                                                                                                                  400, Request ID: 3503cc50-aa63-45ca 
                                                                                                                  -837a-e66085f8e215)" (RequestToken: 
                                                                                                                  c2277c5f-0fa3-cd7f-df01-6c7e19d1ad0 
                                                                                                                  a, HandlerErrorCode:                
                                                                                                                  InvalidRequest)                     
CREATE_FAILED                         AWS::EC2::NatGateway                  NatGatewayA                           Resource creation cancelled         
ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS                  AWS::CloudFormation::Stack            sam4-app                              The following resource(s) failed to 
                                                                                                                  create: [NatGatewayA,               
                                                                                                                  MLModelUploadFunction]. Rollback    
                                                                                                                  requested by user.                  
DELETE_IN_PROGRESS                    AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociati   RouteTableAssociationAPrivate         -                                   
                                      on                                                                                                              
DELETE_IN_PROGRESS                    AWS::IAM::Role                        


.
.
.


           InternetGateway                       -                                   
DELETE_COMPLETE                       AWS::EC2::InternetGateway             InternetGateway                       -                                   
DELETE_COMPLETE                       AWS::EC2::VPC                         EfsLambdaVpc                          -                                   
ROLLBACK_COMPLETE                     AWS::CloudFormation::Stack            sam4-app                              -                                   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: Failed to create/update the stack: sam4-app, Waiter StackCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Stacks[].StackStatus" we matched expected path: "ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" at least once
```

Researching about this error, I noticed that it is a problem with the lambda function. When I access **Applications** in the **AWS Lambda** it shows a creation error.

I tried various solutions like directly specifying the s3 bucket, using another version of sam, I tried running the [MLInference-Lambda-EFS code](https://github.com/debnsuma/MLInference-Lambda-EFS), but nothing works.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem? I have been struggling with this project for a long time.

Comment: I decided to run the older version of the code [MLInference-Lambda-EFS](https://github.com/debnsuma/MLInference-Lambda-EFS) and realized that I don't get this error and successfully build it.

Answer (score 0):

Please run `sam delete --stack-name aws-sam-cli-managed-default` to remove the broken managed stack before going through guided deploy or `--resolve-s3` again.

I ran the deploy command again `sam deploy --s3-bucket test-bucket --guided` and it worked when I specified a bucket name. This bucket is ignored by SAM and the stack is created without problem.

Comment: I followed your solution but it didn't work,. `Error: Stack could not be deleted as it encountered DELETE_FAILED status: aws-sam-cli-managed-default, ex: Waiter StackDeleteComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Stacks[].StackStatus" we matched expected path: "DELETE_FAILED" at least once`